# javascript: best way to check if element exists in pre populated collection?

Tags: javascript

We are creating a function that would return true if input passed is in certain pre-defined values:

```
function isEligbile(input){
    return (input == 1 || input == 24 || input == 17);
}
```

OR

```
function isEligbile(input){
   var eligibleInputs = {1: true, 24: true, 17: true};
   return eligibleInputs[input]; 
}
```

I have just mentioned 3 eligible inputs but list is too long. Which is best approach to do such comparison?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your question. Do you want to check if element exists in array ?

Comment: `int input` in the parameter indicates that you're using a typed language - typescript perhaps? Tag the question as such.

Comment: Don't ask questions with "best way to do something", that is highly subjective and you'll get a bunch of suggestions instead of correct answers, you could create an array and do `indexOf`, `find` or a million other ways. Instead, mention any problems with what you have tried.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Can't be TypeScript, it would be `input: number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an object literal to store your values, just an array from which you can check for authorized values with `indexOf()`:

```
function isEligible(input){
   var eligibleInputs = [1, 24, 17];
   return eligibleInputs.indexOf(input) != -1;
}
```

Please note that in your case the object literal is not a bad choice. It may be longer to write but also faster in execution.

Comment: Downvoted because there's no explanation why this is any better than what the OP suggested. Answers should have explanations. Also, the other suggestion use `include` instead of `indexOf` which is more semantic since you don't care about the index

Comment: @JuanMendes I added some explanations.

Comment: @JuanMendes Also note that if this code is used in browsers, `include` is not supported by older ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about wanting to hardcode the eligible inputs, I would suggest:

```
function isEligible(input) {
    var eligibleInputs = [1, 17, 24];
    return eligibleInputs.includes(input);
}
```

However, if the list of eligible inputs is really long or subject to change, you might want to consider using a different solution, like loading the list from an external source.

The reason I find the snippet above to be a better solution than OPs code is because

- It is easier to expand this list (less characters to type)
- It is a lot more elegant than having an if-statement with an option for every single element
- You can easily iterate over the array if needed for other things

Note: The function in your code is called 'isEligbile' instead of 'isEligible', you might want to fix this.

Comment: You must have not seen palaѕн's answer which has the same thing as you

Comment: That is true, apparently he posted it while I was typing my answer. It seems he deleted it while I was editing it, however

Comment: If this is happening a lot, a map would be more performant so it can do `O(1)` lookups, but the overhead of creating a map may not be worth it if the list is not that big. (Your answer was added 6 minutes after palash's answer)